# Big-O question about finding witnesses.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I'm supposed to find the witnesses for:

$$f(x) = \frac{(x * x! + x^2) }{ (x + 17)}$$ which is Big O$(x^x)$

This is obviously true, I just threw both functions into a graphing program and see that $f(x)$ is always less than $x^x$.

So from there I then try to find the $C$ for a witness. I guess $0.1$, and I see that $f(x)$ is now above $x^x$ until $x > 2.091$ (See picture), so is that $k$? Does it matter than $f(x)$ is still below $x^x$ for a little while before $k$? Any help would be really appreciated.

The red line is $f(x)$ and blue is $0.1 x^x$
[image]

Comment: This isn't relevant, but $f(x) = \frac{(x * x! + x^2) }{ (x + 17)}$ can be simplified to be $\frac{x(x!+x)}{x+17}$ and so on: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+((x*(x!)%2Bx%5E2)%2F(x%2B17)))

Answer (score 1):

An extremely useful inequality is
$(n/e)^n < n! < (n/e)^{n+1}
$.

This follows via induction from
$(1+1/n)^n < e < (1+1/n)^{n+1}
$
which has been proven here
a number of times.

From this,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x) 
&= \dfrac{(x * x! + x^2) }{ (x + 17)}\\
&< \dfrac{(x * (x/e)^{x+1} + x^2) }{ (x + 17)}\\
&= x^x \dfrac{(x^2e^{-(x+1)} + x^{2-x}) }{ (x + 17)}\\
&= x^x x^2\dfrac{(e^{-(x+1)} + x^{-x}) }{ (x + 17)}\\
&< x^x x((e^{-(x+1)} + x^{-x}))\\
&< x^x xe^{-x}((e^{-1} + (x/e)^{-x}))\\
&< x^x xe^{-x}
\qquad\text{for }x > 8\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: This seems to be quite a bit ahead of where we are in discrete mathematics. We are just supposed to find witnesses C and k for the function. C being just a constant multiplied by x^x.

Comment: Then just use $x! < x^x$.